# PHP - Not receiving email from contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

I am not receiving emails from this contact form, but the message seems to sending okay and it also redirects me to the sent page.
I don't have access to the server only via FTP.

---

PHP

---

```
<?php
$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

<html>

<p><h3>Email Submited From Website.</h3></p>

<p><strong>Name:</strong> $name</p>
<p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
<p><strong>Subject:</strong> $subject</p>
<p><strong>Message:</strong> $comment</p>

</html>

EMAIL;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: test email' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <website@mt.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";


if ($_POST['submit']){
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
header ("Location: message-sent.php");
die();
} else {
header ("Location: message-failed.php");
die();
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please ask to the server provider to enable mail setting on the server. It seems that mail setting are not enabled on your server. thanks.

Comment: Before I try and contact them, is there any way to test this?

Comment: try to add  error reporting at the top of your php code  and check once.

Comment: I'm flagging to close as this is a server configuration issue, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mail is actually being sent:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)===false) {
    echo "Not sent!";
} else {
    echo "Sent!";
}
```

Comment: Are your credentials correct ? Can You log to mail with them successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$headers .= 'To: test email' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <website@mt.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
```

To this:

```
$headers .= "To: $to <test email>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: website@mt.co.uk <website@mt.co.uk>\r\n";
```

Also, you need to sanitize the subject and body of the email so that the email arrives, but this will usually be reflected in the results after email() reports a success, in that case the email will bounce, go to the spambox, or simply be refused.

Answer (score -1):

If your hosting provider doesn't have an email server, you could try to use a free email server and phpMailer. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Do I need access to the c-panel to install PHPMailer or can I install it via FTP?

Comment: Via FTP it is basically just a folder you upload and put with the rest of your site's files.

Comment: Fantastic I will give it a try.

Comment: If you haven't already seen, there is an example of how to use php mailer here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

Comment: I am still waiting on word from the hosting provider

Comment: Ok, if you don't get an email server maybe use a free email server hosting company and phpMailer to send The mail.

Comment: I was thinking of that but, don't I need the SMTP login details I do not have access to these and would also need to contact the provider for this.

Comment: Yeah, you need to have the credentials